# Harmonic motion of negative charge between two positive ones

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, harmonic-oscillator

I have to prove that a negative charge will execute an harmonic motion when placed in the line that separates two positive charges $Q$. (The negative charge $-q$ will not be placed on the center).
I clearly understand that it will be an harmonic motion, but i can't show it mathematically: i've tried the traditional way:
Let the two positive charges be $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, and the position of the $-q$ charge is at an $X$ distance from the center:
$$F_1 - F_2 = ma$$
Where
$$F_1 = \frac{kQ_1q}{(d/2 -x)^2}$$
And
$$F_2 = \frac{kQ_2q}{(d/2 + x)^2}$$
The problem is that im not being able to change this equation in order to get the traditional simple harmonic motion differential equation.
Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: This is a really good question. No idea why this was closed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The motion cannot be along the line joining the +ve charges because such motion is unstable : the -ve charge would accelerate away from the centre point and towards the nearest +ve charge.

I think it must be assumed that the -ve charge moves along the perpendicular bisector of the two +ve charges, and is constrained to remain on this line.It must be constrained because this motion is again unstable : the smallest deviation either side will result in acceleration towards one of the charges.

Suppose the two +ve charges are $2d$ apart and the -ve charge is distance $y$ from their midpoint along the perpendicular bisector. I am using $y$ to distinguish transverse displacement from longitudinal displacement $x$ along the line joining the +ve charges.

Then the distance $r$ between the -ve and +ve charges is given by $r^2=d^2+y^2$ and the force of attraction to either charge is $kQq/r^2$. The total of the components of these forces along the bisector is the restoring force
$F=2(kQq/r^2)(y/r)=2kQq(y/r^3)$.

For small values of $y<<d$ we have $r^3 \approx d^3$ so the equation of motion is :
$m\ddot y = -F = -2kQq(y/d^3)$
$\ddot y + \omega^2 y = 0$
where $\omega^2=2kQq/md^3$.

The oscillation is only harmonic for small displacements $y<<d$.

Comment: Stability is a mathematical concept - can you demonstrate that it is unstable mathematically? "Because I say so" works sometimes, but math always has the final word. (I'm trying to but I'm rusty). Need to integrate over $(\frac{d}{2} \pm x) \ / \ \lvert \frac{d}{2} \pm x \rvert^3 $.

Comment: @uhoh : I don't think mathematics is necessary to recognise instability here. In this scenario if the -ve charge is closer to one of the +ve charges than the other, the net force on it will be away from the central position, and will increase as that asymmetry increases.

Comment: *If* they are supposed to be co-linear in the problem, could the negative charge just pass through the other charge, then turn around and pass through again? The problem doesn't say "proton" or "ion", just charges Q and -q, which are purely mathematical constructs. Anyway I have a hunch your (and @knzhou 's) interpretation might be right - the problem might assume the initial position  is displaced *perpendicularly* to the line connecting the other two.

Comment: @uhoh : That's an interesting suggestion. I don't know how that would work mathematically, passing through a point of infinite potential energy $-kQq/r$ as $r \to 0$. If it does work I think it would be difficult to calculate the period. If all 3 charges were +ve then co-linear oscillation is possible, but again unstable against lateral perturbations.

Comment: The question is good, this is what a solution [looks like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jZjuS.gif) from [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Three_body_problem).

Comment: @uhoh : The -ve charge seems to 'bounce' off the +ve charges when it reaches them, instead of 'passing through' as you suggest above. That does not seem right. Why should it change direction like that? Why should it be attracted when it is moving towards a +ve charge then repelled when it is moving away?

Comment: It's a good question! It's possible that the animation has a mistake - for example the person who did the animation used a short cut which fails to swap the colors of the two. Actually it looks a lot like three mutually attracting (e.g. gravity) particles and the red color is simply jumping to whichever is in between the other two. I think you are right - this looks incorrect indeed!

Comment: I found [this plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qesyy.png) in [A Topological Existence Proof for the Schubart Orbits in the Collinear Three-Body Problem - Richard Moeckel](http://www.math.umn.edu/~rmoeckel/research/CollinearExistence5.pdf). It seems the GIF may not be wrong after all! Imagine a hyperbolic orbit between two planets that swing past each other (attractive 1/r^2 force), if you zoom out far enough that you can't resolve the closest-approach distance, they would just seem to bounce off each other. Granted that paper is for gravity not charge. This gets more and more interesting!

Comment: Yes this is very interesting indeed. I was not aware such solutions are possible. Your animation looks like Fig.1. Yes, I suppose the lighter particle passes infinitesimally close to the heavier point particles, and 'sling shots' back, which looks like 'bouncing off'. That the 2 heavier particles do not get any closer and collide with each other is also remarkable, but not impossible. Great find. Well done for continuing to dig. (Can you work out the angular frequency?!)

Comment: @uhoh I didn't really understand the collinear case. (You provided citations but I am not acquainted with that level of details). Can you explain why the balls negative charge move towards the positive charge and suddenly bounce off at the end. Why don't they remain stuck happily forever?

Comment: @tatan the OP's question talks about charges (suggests they have charge) that move with simple harmonic motion (suggest they have mass also). Beyond that, there's nothing in the OP's question that would provide a "sticking" mechanism. It's a simple math problem without a lot of reality to it, so you have to make the fewest assumptions possible.

Comment: @uhoh Ok. But if someone gave you the problem -"What do you think would happen if in the above mentioned case you displaced the middle charge along the line joining the other two charged?"... would you readily answer its simple harmonic? If yes,why ?

Comment: @tatan SHM is a helpful approximation in many physics problems even if a more detailed analysis gives something different. In this case I think it's still unclear about the amplitude and more importantly the direction of motion, so I would not answer.